# Functional Equation of Rectangular Graphs

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

We can characterize affine hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^d$ as sets
$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d \;|\; x^T a + b = 0\}$$
or similiarly quadratic objects (such as a parabola) as sets
$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d \;|\; x^TAx + b^Tx + c = 0\}$$

Is there a way to explicitely characterize an axis-aligned graph like a rectangle?
Is there a general function $f$ such that the boundary of some union of rectangles becomes
$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d \;|\; f(x) = 0\}$$

Comment: What do you mean by a rectangle when $d$ is large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation
$$
   \max\{|x_1|, |x_2|, \dots, |x_d|\} = 1
$$
gives us a hypercube of side length $2$ centered at the origin. This can be simplified to an expression with absolute values only, but a messy one: we have $\max\{A,B\} = \frac{A+B +|A-B|}{2}$, and we can chain this together to write a max of $d$ values using absolute values. When $d=2$, we have a nicer expression with absolute values: $$|x_1 + x_2| + |x_1 - x_2| = 2.$$
This gives us a square of side length $2$ centered at $(0,0)$

By replacing each $x_i$ with some linear function of $x_i$, we can move the hypercube (or square) to another center, and scale the sides independently, so we get an arbitrary cuboid (or rectangle).

Comment: Thanks, this helps. What can I do to describe more complex rectilinear shapes (boundary of unions of rectangles)?

Comment: If $f(x)=0$ describes one shape and $g(x) = 0$ describes another, then $f(x) \cdot g(x) = 0$ describes their union. Does that help?